# When using the K155ID1 IC, some numbers of Nixie tubes do not emit properly

Tags: nixie

I'm beginner of electronics. (Please understand that I have used Google Translator.) 
I connected the IN-14 Nixie tube to the K155ID1 IC. But the numbers in the Nixie tube do not completely emit. When MPSA42 transistor is used, even the higher current limiting resistor normaly emits light, but now it does not emit light completely even when the resistance of the current limiting resistor's value is lowered. Strangely enough, however, the number 6 was completely luminescent.
[image: 6 - fully illuminated]
[image: 0 - Does not emit light completely]
[image: 4 - Does not emit light completely]
And here's the circuit diagram.
[image: circuit diagram]
 I connected the cathode of each Nixie tube to each pin of K155ID1, and the BCD input was operated by a switch that connected a 4.7k pullup resistor. The Nixie tube was powered by about 180VDC. 
Please tell me how to make the Nixie tube digit flash perfectly.

Comment: If you connect one of the cathodes directly to ground does it light up properly?

Comment: yes. all the cathodes work normally.

Comment: Sounds like a duff chip or it's not being connected up properly. Please post a schematic diagram so we can see how it's wired.

Comment: I tested the chip with LEDs, but the chip works well.

Comment: When I removed the pullup resistor and connected the BCD input pin directly to 5V or GND, the number of Nixie tubes shone normally.

Comment: Are you sure your pullup resistors aren't dragging the 5V supply down? What value are they?

Comment: They're 4.7k. The strange thing is that I did not have any problems when I connected the following. VCC-SW-4.7K-k155id1.

Comment: They shouldn't be causing a problem but you could try making the resistors higher, try 22K.

Comment: Since there is no need for a pull-up resistor when using the MCU, is there any problem in using the MCU to operate the chip? And if the resistance value of the pull-up resistor is low, why does the Nixie tube not display properly?

Comment: Possible cause may be oscillations somewhere, or oscillating power supply (logic or anode). Also, take in mind that internal breakdown diodes on IC's outputs are not supposed for continuous use, the IC will degrade in this case, datasheet says about this. Tube blanking should be done through anode voltage supply.

Answer (score 1):

Try anode resistor 33 - 18 -15 -  10K
k155ID1 internal zener diode 60v, pull-up resistor connected +5v  is 15 - 33K.

Kathode (digit ) 'poisoning' - when highter currentt it shine well.
Change back to 27 -33K when OK.